# How do you say "To take a gap year"?

Tags: translation, word

Is there a clear translation for the phrase "Take a gap year" (i.e. take a year off between your last year of high school and college (often for travel, work, etc.))?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a 'clear' translation because of the culture difference behind it. Chinese people don't take a gap year until very recently and the few who do are still considered rebel by many. It hasn't become that popular yet to have a well-known terminology. In some circles it's just called `gap year`, `gap年` or `间隔年`.

`间隔年` is probably the best option for now, but you may still want to define or explain it to the audience beforehand. This translation has actually made its entry on [Baidu Baike](http://baike.baidu.com/view/1637881.htm) and appeared in a book title [迟到的间隔年](http://baike.baidu.com/view/2804451.htm).

You can see how some people still refer to the concept as 'gap year' in discussions like [this](http://www.douban.com/group/topic/34111494/), which suggests the Chinese term hasn't got its full popularity yet.

As for the verb ('take'), I think the best context-free translation is `体验` (to experience). Depending on the context you can also use `开始` (to start) or `要` (to have). E.g.

> He decided to take a gap year after graduation. 他决定毕业后体验间隔年 (formal) or 他决定要个间隔年 (colloquial).
>
> His friends took a gap year right after graduation, but he didn't. 他的朋友们一毕业就开始了间隔年，但是他没有。

Comment: How would you say "take" in this case then? 
"做个间隔年？“

Comment: @Stephen 做个间隔年 doesn't sound good. Depending on the context you can say 开始间隔年 or 体验间隔年. See my update to the answer.

Comment: If I need to say "I'll take a gap year before college," I would say "大学前我间隔了一年" and use 间隔 as a verb.

Answer (score 1):

We call it `'间隔年'` in Chinese. And there are some books telling stories about the gap year experience of chinese young guys. You can find them on amazon, for example ['迟到的间隔年'](http://www.amazon.cn/gp/product/B002OED6QK/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d0_i1_gs9w) http://www.amazon.cn/gp/product/B002OED6QK/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d0_i1_gs9w  ('A gap year for being late' translated in English) .